# What is the meaning of SETTINGS_HEADER_TABLE_SIZE in http2's SETTINGS frame?

Tags: http2

I want to know whether this parameter is sent by decoder and used to limit the encoder.

For example, a client receives a SETTINGS frame from a server with a parameter `SETTINGS_HEADER_TABLE_SIZE = 1024 bytes`. Does this parameter mean that the max memory, which the client can use to deflate the request headers, is 1024 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

The `SETTINGS_HEADER_TABLE_SIZE` parameter indicates the size of the dynamic table as specified in [RFC 7541](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7541) (also known as HPACK encoding).

The particular section you want to look at to understand what is the header table size is [RFC 7541, section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7541#section-4).

This parameter is *related* to the max memory that is allocated for each connection, but its value does not represent the actual number of bytes of memory used by the HPACK encoding.

This parameter can be changed dynamically by either peer as specified in [RFC 7540, section 6.5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6.5.2).

Comment: I can understand. Could you explain my example? If the client receives `SETTINGS_HEADER_TABLE_SIZE = 1024 bytes` in SETTINGS frame, does it mean the client can update the HPACK's dynamic table max to 1024 bytes ?

Comment: It means the client must update the HPACK dynamic table **size** to 1024 entries. The details of how this is done depend on what implementation you are using.

Comment: Why must the client update it to 1024? (The `entries` should be `octets` or `bytes`?) I think the client can update the dynamic table into any size less than or equal to 1024 bytes.